# How to abort called ajax method c# .net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net, ajax

I have a ajax.cs class and I am calling methods from javascript side. So for this I registered it on default.aspx page load like this.

```
Ajax.Utility.RegisterTypeForAjax(typeof(ajax));
```

Sometimes some methods taking a long time, At that time I want to abort this call. How can I abort this request?

I call method like this from js;

```
ajax.testMethod()
```

Comment: What does your method `testMethod()` had inside? are you building the request with the url, error function, success function and so?

Comment: it does not matter what testMethod had inside. I didn't build the request with the url beacuse I just register and use it.

Answer (score 0):

If you make your controller action return a Task, then you can have cancellation token as a parameter to the action. And this cancellation token is automatically triggered when the HTTP request is aborted. And in the action, you can handle the token however you like to cancel the long-running operation.

Comment: I am working with web forms not mvc, so How can I implement your suggestion. Actually I am not sure understand your case. Could you share an example or document link?

Comment: Is your question a duplicate of this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26204378/cancelling-long-running-tasks-asp-net

Comment: No, My question is not same it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it works, but instead of aborting the ajax from the C# side, why don't you cancel it from the js side? in your ajax configuration, you can add a timeout parameter which, when happens, triggers the .error() function you can define, or leave it blank if you just want it to stop executing.

For js:

```
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.post('your url');
ajax.timeout(10000); //or any time in milliseconds to set a timeout.
ajax.ontimeout= function(){ }//optional, just if you want a callback when ajax times out
```

For jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
   url:'yoururl',
   timeout: 10000,
   error: function(){
   }
});
```

Comment: I am not calling ajax method like your write. I just register on .cs side with "RegisterTypeForAjax" and use it from js.